# Can I create less of an attraction between two colliders?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics

I have colliders that when one lands on the other, should act as a platform they can stand/ride on. When they hit each other (like in the video attached), the two should never stay connected, and perhaps maybe bounce off. For that, I tried adding a Slippery (0 friction) physics 2 material to the player, no luck.

How can I achieve less of an attraction when two colliders hit each other this way?

Video: https://i.imgur.com/uf1JqWi.mp4

Player Collider 
(Slippery is 0 friction, 0 bounciness):
[image]

The flying platform (same material):

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a bounciness of zero, so there is no bounce off => set it to one and see if it changes

Comment: I've just tried values from .5 to 10, incrementally increasing. What this added was very different from what I expected, it had no effect at low numbers and starting at 5 or so if I hit the platform/flat bit (correctly), it would bounce straight back aggressively/fast.

Answer (score 0):

[PhysicMaterial Docu:](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html)

> **`Bounciness`**:
>      How bouncy is the surface? A value of 0 will **not bounce**. A value of 1 will bounce without any loss of energy, certain approximations are to be expected though that might add small amounts of energy to the simulation.

You should change the bounciness to something `> 0`.

But also be aware of [PhysicsManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html)

> **`Bounce Threshold`**
>   Set a velocity value. If two colliding objects have a relative velocity below this value, they do **not bounce** off each other. This value also reduces jitter, so it is not recommended to set it to a very low value.

Comment: I've just tried values from .5 to 10, incrementally increasing. What this added was very different from what I expected, it had no effect at low numbers and starting at 5 or so if I hit the platform/flat bit (correctly), it would bounce straight back aggressively/fast.

Comment: you should probably add it only to the one moving platform ... not the player in general.

Comment: Yeah I've only added it on the collider for the moving platform. No luck yet, still trying!